# XCode iOS : How to get 'apple-touch-icon url' in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, apple-touch-icon

XCode iOS : How to get 'apple-touch-icon url' in UIWebView?

I want to save image in web-site 'apple-touch-icon'.